# Update database from foreach loop with returned bool

Tags: c#, foreach, sql-update, luhn

i have a set off CCNs i need to perform a luhn check on. I have most of the code working, but now i need to update my database with the results so i know which cards are valid. here is some of the code I am using:

```
        int valid;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {

            string cardNumber = dr["cardNumber"].ToString();
            Console.WriteLine ("{0} is {1}valid", cardNumber, cardNumber.ToString().LuhnCheck() ? "" : "not ");

            valid = /*some code here*/;

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update MyTable SET LuhnSatisfied =" + valid + " where cardNumber =" + cardNumber, con);           
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();          

        }
```

my console.writeline statement calls the LuhnCheck method which returns a 0 or a 1. I need to capture those results in a variable, so i can concatenate that into my update statement. any Ideas how to do that? Here is the rest of the luhnCheck code

```
    public static class Luhn
    {
        public static bool LuhnCheck(this string cardNumber)
        {
            return LuhnCheck(cardNumber.Select(c => c - '0').ToArray());
        }

        static readonly int[] results = { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };

        private static bool LuhnCheck(this int[] digits)
        {
            int checkValue = GetCheckValue(digits);
            return checkValue == 0;
        }

        private static int GetCheckValue(int[] digits)
        {
            int i = 0;
            int lengthMod = digits.Length % 2;
            return digits.Sum(d => i++ % 2 == lengthMod ? results[d] : d) % 10;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I hope you have a process that reads the credit card numbers from the table and encrypts it. Storing CCNs in this form is an invitation for the Database to be hacked.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    string cardNumber = dr["cardNumber"].ToString();
    bool isValid = cardNumber.ToString().LuhnCheck();
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is {1}valid", cardNumber, isValid  ? "" : "not ");

    string isValidSqlBool = isValid ? "1" : "0";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update MyTable SET LuhnSatisfied = " + isValidSqlBool + " where cardNumber =" + cardNumber, con);           
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```